# Rails 6 Tasks with arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

// This is a question for Ruby on Rails

I have a Rails Tasks that should take arguments from command line.

Looks like this :

```
 task update: :environment do

if (ARGV[1] == "DEBUG")
  DEBUG = true
else
  DEBUG = false
end
```

Now I can run the command line :

> **rails call:update DEBUG**

and it works !

But after the task was finished I got also the message :

```
rails aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'DEBUG' (See the list of available tasks with `rails --tasks`)
```

I looking already around the community, but all what I found was quite old and seems not to be compatible with Rails 6 ! So thats the reason why I asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try with the code you shared above I got the same error of rake abort.

its Comming because they way you calling the rake task with the argument it assume the `DEBUG` is another task so it try to find and give this error.

Here is proper way of doing it
I did some modification in the code to get rid of the error use the following code it will work perfectly

```
task :update, [:value] => [:environment] do |t, args|
  if (args[:value] == "DEBUG")
    DEBUG = true
    p "Value is True"
  else
    DEBUG = false
    p "Value is False"
  end
end
```

it works perfectly 
[image]

You can also put this task in the namespace and then call it from there as well

```
namespace :debug_task do
 # task code here what I mentioned above 
end
```

and then call it to form the terminal like this

```
rake debug_task:update["DEBUG"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for fast answer, yes its works also for me ! Thanks.
But is there also a way to omit the rocket operator and use symbols instead ?
([:value] => [:environment])